# Use LaunchImage Asset as a backgroundImage on Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, background-image, iphone-x

I'm updating an app for iPhone X. App has a background image which fulfills whole screen. It has @1, @2 and @3 dimensions. However, It looks stretched on iPhone X because of different aspect ratio. As I see only Launch Screen Image Asset has iPhone X option. Can I create a new Launch Screen Image Asset and add my background image to it and use it in UIImageView or Is there any better approach to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried to set the Content Mode to Aspect Fill? There would be some clipping when you do this though.

Comment: Yes. I don't want a clipping.

Comment: @3x is suitable for [i-phone X](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/image-size-and-resolution/) . There is one BAD way to do is check iOS device at runtime at set particular image for iPhone-X